# Null foreign key values in the child table are not be included in the result set

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working on creating Web API using ASP.NET Core. I have created a method to retrieve employees who are not in a specified role.

Consider this method implementation to return employees who are not in the specified role.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeesNotInRoleAsync(int roleId)
{
    var employees = await (from employee in this.dataContext.Employees
                       where employee.RoleId != roleId
                       select new Employee
                       {
                           Id = employee.Id,
                           Name = employee.FullName,
                           Status = employee.Name,
                           RoleId = employee.RoleId,
                        }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
 
    return employees;
}
```

The RoleId of the employee is nullable integer. So, it can have null value too.

The RoleId column is nullable int column in the database Employees table and it is having foreign key relationship with ID column in the EmployeeRoles table.
The problem I'm facing is, the query doesn't return the employees with RoleId value as Null. Please explain what it the reason and how to resolve this.

Even when I retrieve all the records from Employees table using Linq query without any where condition, records which have null value for RoleId column is not retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

The query in question will result in SQL in something like `where RoleId <> ...` and when comparing value to `NULL` and in SQL it is not possible to test for `NULL` values with comparison operators, such as `=`, `<`, or `<>`, i.e. such test will always result in `false` when one of operands is `null`, valid SQL syntax for null check is `IS [NOT] NULL`, so if you want to include nulls in query try changing the LINQ code:

```cs
from employee in this.dataContext.Employees
where employee.RoleId != roleId || employee.RoleId == null
...
```

Though as far as I remember at least in later EF Core version it should (if not explicitly disabled) be supported out of the box (but will need to check).

Read also:

- [Query null semantics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/null-comparisons)

Comment: Hi Guru Stron, Thanks for the suggestion. I have tried some changes in the query by adding  condition as employee.RoleId == null or !employee.RoleId.HasValue. But still it doesn't include values with null roleId. Sorry to mention this before. Is there anything I need to check with Database Table properties?

Comment: @MohanramAnbukkarasu please share the generated SQL.

Comment: @MohanramAnbukkarasu Also just a guess - try adding `IgnoreQueryFilters()` i.e. something like `from this.dataContext.Employees.IgnoreQueryFilters()`

Answer (score 0):

I think that the issue is with Lazy Loading, the query is failing to load related entities.
You can try eager loading with the below query:

```
var employees = await (from employee in this.dataContext.Employees.Include('EmployeeRoles')
                   where employee.RoleId != roleId
                   select new Employee
                   {
                       Id = employee.Id,
                       Name = employee.FullName,
                       Status = employee.Name,
                       RoleId = employee.RoleId,
                    }).ToListAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);

return employees;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Employee>> GetEmployeesNotInRoleAsync(int roleId)
{
    var employees = await dataContext.Employees
        .Where(employee => employee.RoleId != roleId || employee.RoleId == null)
        .Select(employee => new Employee
        {
            Id = employee.Id,
            Name = employee.FullName,
            Status = employee.Name,
            RoleId = employee.RoleId,
        })
        .ToListAsync()
        .ConfigureAwait(false);
 
    return employees;
}
```